# Send a text message directly from an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a simple question on whether or not it is possible to send a text message from the iPhone using an app I developed, or whether I would need to use a 3rd party messaging service for this like Twilio.  I have found that the answer to this is no, as of a few years ago, but I wasn't sure if anything had changed and wanted to be sure.

Thank You!

Comment: Are asking about sending a text message without using MFMessageComposeViewController? Nothing has changed in this regard in many years (if ever).

Comment: I go with @rmaddy's suggestion of using MFMessageComposeViewController for acheiving the same. Appcoda has a nice tutorial for the same, https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/

Comment: @KarthickRamesh No, I'm not suggesting its use. I'm asking the OP to clarify their question. If they don't wish to use `MFMessageComposeViewController` then their search results that seem old are still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer us no without an API like Twilio, ZipWhip or Plivo. You can, however, create a message when the user taps a link via the "sms:" URL scheme. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send text messages. The only thing you can do is to open pre-composed message creator with filled in number and content but user has to tap the send button.